# Cardinality of an orthonormal basis of $l^2(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, hilbert-spaces

How can one prove that the cardinality of an orthonormal basis of $l^2(A)$ is exactly the cardinality of $A$? I would like to use this result to show that $l^2(A)$ is Hilbert-isomorphic to $l^2(B)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality.

---

Any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself more clearly!

Comment: You can try to show that the cardinality of $A$ is the dimension of a minimal dense subspace of $\ell^2(A)$, or something like that. I think in the infinite case it's also the size of a minimal dense subset which may be easier.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I have read that the functions $\{\phi:A \to \Bbb C: \phi = \chi_{a}, a \in A\}$ form an orthonormal basis and that can be checked using the fact that its span contains the set of simple functions in $l^2(A)$, whose closure is dense in $l^2(A)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It is stated in Rudin's "Real and complex analysis" (page 86) without any restriction on $A$ but also without a proof or a reference. I tried to prove it in the following pdf using stuff I found on wikipedia, wikiproof and on this forum: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N6y_0T2YDb0uB9SQ-9ulIvCmoKZoa_hN/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: My apologies. I see that I somehow dropped "orthonormal basis of" when I read the question, and thought that you were comparing the cardinalities of $A$ and $\ell^2(A)$ in its entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I tried to prove it by putting together stuff that I found online (mainly wikipedia, wikiproof and this forum) and by adding some propositions and the concept of Hilbert-dimension. You can find my attempt at the following link (to the pdf): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N6y_0T2YDb0uB9SQ-9ulIvCmoKZoa_hN/view?usp=drive_link

Let me know if there are errors (both mathematical and grammatical/syntactic).